# Relationship between logit and odds ratios

Tags: logistic, logit, ratio, odds

Alright so I am trying to sort out exactly what a logit is in terms of a ratio...

I understand that :

$logit(p) = log(\frac{p}{1-p}) = \beta$

and that

$exp(\beta) =$ odds ratio =$ \frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}}{\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}}$

I guess what's not coming across is how $\beta$, not being a ratio of odds, converts to the odds ratio metric, when taken out of logarithmic space.

To provide a bit more, if this is the logistic regression equation for the constant

$log(\frac{p}{1-p}) = \beta + \beta_1*0 + \beta_2*0 + \beta_3*0 + \beta_4*0 + \beta_5*0$.

then $exp(\beta)$ = odds ratio

so likewise for

$log(\frac{p}{1-p}) = \beta + \beta_1*1$

then $exp(\beta+\beta_1*1)$ = odds ratio for a one unit increase in $\beta_1$

BUT, how does

$$exp(\beta+\beta_1*1) = \frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}}{\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}}\tag{1}$$

because doesn't the $+$ in log terms (e.g. $\beta+\beta_1*1$) equal a multiplication and not a division?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misunderstanding is in **(1)**. In fact  $exp(\beta+\beta_1*1)\neq \frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}}{\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}}$

You already know $log(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}) = \beta + \beta_1*1$ then

$exp(\beta+\beta_1*1)=\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}$ it is an **odds** not an **odds ratio**.

while the $exp(\beta_1)$ itself indeed is an odds ration, since $OR=\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}/\frac{p_0}{1-p_0}=\frac{exp(\beta+\beta_1*1)}{exp(\beta+\beta_1*0)}=e^{\beta+\beta_1-\beta-0*\beta_1}=exp{(\beta_1)}$ suppose you have a binary(dummy) predictor variable or when it is a continuous variable you are talking about one unit change of the variable..

Also note $exp(\beta) =$  odds ratio  =$ \frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}}{\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}}$ is not correct either.

Comment: Thank you for replying.
So, exp(β1) is an odds ratio. and β1 is log odds.

$OR=\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}/\frac{p_0}{1-p_0}=\frac{exp(\beta+\beta_1*1)}{exp(\beta+\beta_1*0)}=exp{(\beta_1)}$

If you take the log of both sides of this equation, are you left with 

$\frac{\beta+\beta_1*1}{\beta+\beta_1*0}=\beta_1$

Comment: Sorry ran out of editing time, so things are a wee bit wonky.
Thanks for looking @deepNorth

Comment: $\beta_1$ is not log odds.  You just think this way, suppose the mode is $log(\frac{p}{1-p}) = \beta + \beta_1*x$  and $x=1$ or $x=0$ when $x=1$ you can calculate the odds for $x=1$ from the model and when $x=0$ you can calculate odds for $x=0$ then you  compare the two odds you get odds ratio.

Comment: i see.  so the logit does not need to be a ratio of odds, but when you take the exp(logit) it does represent the ratio of odds for that particular variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: cool. and just to be finalize this: β1 is the regression coefficient for a one unit change in β1, but that is measured in log odds.
and
a logit is equal to:
$log(\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}) = \beta + \beta_1*1$

Comment: oh, and is there anything specifically called the "log odds ratio"

Comment: yes, the log odds ratio is the logarithm of the odds ratio, wich is $\beta_1$. If you take the exponential of the logarithm of the odds ratio, then you end up with the odds ratio. The log odds is **not** $\beta_1$, but $\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_k x_k = \ln(\frac{p}{1-p})$. The odds is $\exp(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \cdots + \beta_k x_k) = \exp(\ln(\frac{p}{1-p})) = \frac{p}{1-p}$

Comment: I think there are some confusions  on definition of odds, odds is defined as  $\frac{p}{1-p}$

Comment: thanks.  so log odds ratios are the β, which are the logistic regression coefficients.